# Using variable from controller in an if statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a variable that is passed from the controller. It works fine when I just have it rendered as HTML however I am trying to use it in a PHP if statement and in this case it is saying that it doesn't exist.

```
@if ([[private_count]] != 0)
     <div>Content</div>
@endif
```

I think it has to do with calling the [[]] shorthand within PHP but how else would  I be able to use it to compare?

Comment: The shorthand is not `[[]]` but `{{}}`.

Comment: Interestingly the brackets also work outside of php code.

Comment: They work outside the PHP only. That's Blade...

Comment: Yes, that has been my lession from this post! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blades `@if` directive is just a wrapper around PHPs native `if`:

```
@if($private_count != 0)
    <div>Content</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use simple php code also.

```
 <?php if(condition ){ ... }?>
```

It also works with .blade template

Comment: using php in blade doesn't make any sense. .blade.php is suppose to be just blade